# Is there a way around the "Content mismatch between AMP and canonical pages" error?

Tags: amp-html, google-search-console

This shows up as a critical issue in the google search console, even though the canonical version and the AMP are, in my opinion, ["essentially the same."](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6328309#error_list)

Steps to resolve this issue can be found in the link above. I followed them and concluded that the general content of the AMP and canonical page were determined not to be the same.

**Here's why (I think..)**

In order to build an AMP version of a page, I had to remove a dynamically created google maps (because it used javascript, not allowed in AMPs), and replace it with an amp-iframe embedded google maps ([like this](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/)). So I think this "difference" between the canonical version (dynamically created in divs) and the AMP (using amp-iframe) triggers the error even though the page content is ultimately the same.

Can this be remedied? How does google decide if the AMP and canonical page have "essentially the same" content?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I already linked the AMP to the canonical page, and vice versa. See the links in Lovntola's comment or noogui's response

Comment: Do you mean this: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery

Comment: Yep! I already linked the pages. I'll edit my post to include that. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a link to your page?